# Is there a option to see how many users using which version of my app?

Tags: flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to see percentage of users that using different versions of my app.

I've tried to look for different sections in app store connect analytics but could not find anything.

Comment: You can check out Amplitude https://pub.dev/packages/amplitude_flutter

Comment: Thanks, app stores built in visualization was helpful enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the number your app user based on version in :

`Trends->Units->Select you app name->Click Version Tabs->Change time filter to Lifetime of whenever you want.`

see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owX5O.png).

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase offers analytics services which provide full tracking for each version of your app your users use, and a compare graphs between them

[image: Firebase analytucs]

Comment: Oh that is actually what I want but I don't use firebase